# Add space after - in a value when there is no space after it

Tags: r, dplyr

Based on the data below how can I add a space after the special character `-` only when there is no space after it which in this case is for fiscal year `2012 -2013`? I know I have to use `gsub` but, it always confuses me so some explanation would be appreciated.

Sample data and code:

```
id = c (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
FiscalYear = c("2012 -2013", "2012 -2013", "2012 -2013", "2012 -2013", "2012 -2013",
               "2014 - 2015", "2014 - 2015", "2014 - 2015", "2014 - 2015", "2014 - 2015")
# Sample
df = data.frame(id, FiscalYear)

# Updated Sample
df_new = df %>% mutate(FiscalYear = ifelse(....))

# str_pad does not work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using some regex you could do:

```r
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  mutate(FiscalYear = gsub("\\-(\\d)", "- \\1", FiscalYear))
#>    id  FiscalYear
#> 1   1 2012 - 2013
#> 2   2 2012 - 2013
#> 3   3 2012 - 2013
#> 4   4 2012 - 2013
#> 5   5 2012 - 2013
#> 6   6 2014 - 2015
#> 7   7 2014 - 2015
#> 8   8 2014 - 2015
#> 9   9 2014 - 2015
#> 10 10 2014 - 2015
```

Comment: Can you please explain the the `gsub` i.e. `"\\-(\\d), "- \\1"`, function as it always confuses me, thank you?

Comment: Also is `%>%` same as `|>`?

Comment: Not 100% the same. `|>` is the native pipe. Most of. the time it works the same as when using the `magrittr` pipe `%>%`. But there are some exceptions.

Comment: And for the regex: `\\-(\\d)` matches a hyphen followed by digit. The `(\\d)` captures the digit. Doing so we can insert the captured digit using `\\1`, i.e. `- \\1` replaces a match by a hyphen, adds a space and finally inserts the captured digit via \\1.